# Is ORM supported by ColdFusion 11?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, cfml

Mapping Two cfc objects via ORM, on execution a Dump shows the data for only one parent cfc object for `table=products` while the array of cfc `table=department` is coming back as (empty string) in output .

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="products" >
  <cfproperty name="productID" column="id" fieldtype="id"  type="numeric" generator="increment">
  <cfproperty name="name">
  <cfproperty name="price">
  <cfproperty name="description">
  <cfproperty name="imageurl">
  <cfproperty name="departmt" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="departmt" fkcolumn="dept_id" lazy="true">
```

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="department">
  <cfproperty name="id" column="dept_id" fieldtype="id" type="numeric" generator="increment">
  <cfproperty name="name" column="dept_name">
  <cfproperty name="location" >
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: 1. What do you get when you do a dump? 2. Get rid of  `lazy="true"`

Comment: thanks @JamesAMohler , i tried by without lazy="true" but got same error . Infact there was a mistake in DB regarding Missing Foreign-Key Column, Resolving that issue i got rid off this error.

Comment: You should do a writeup on what the problem was and how you fount it. That would be useful for the next person.